# How to check if the email address exist?

Tags: php

Recently I notice that some people register with a false email like "blablabla@blablabla.bla"

i want to check if the email entered in the registration form is valid and exist

and thank you ..

i don' want to send anything :/ when i search i find some thing called Mx record how to use it ?

Comment: Send an email to the address, if you get an email back saying "huh?" it's a correct email address. It's like phone numbers, or post addresses, how do you know they're valid? _you don't_ (unless you interact with it)

Comment: Resolve the domain name?

Comment: @MartinJames — That will only tell you if the domain exists.

Comment: i can't found solution can someone help me ?

Comment: Frits above in the first comment gave you the answer. You cannot know if an email exists without sending an email to it and getting a reply in one form or another.

Comment: No One of your solution work can you help me ??

Answer (score 4):

Send the email address in question an email with a link back to your website. This link should contain a unique token that is tied to the user account in question (or, you can simply add the user's ID to the URL as well, so that you know what account to validate the token against). When the user clicks on it, your site should validate the token. If the token is valid, your application can assume that the email address in question exists and that it belongs to the user. Example link:

> `http://mywebsite.com/validate.php?user=2934&validate=37dbhjibh8879uhe98098ushy89d3dd3`

Where `2934` is the user ID and `37dbhjibh8879uhe98098ushy89d3dd3` is the token that you sent out and need to validate.

When the user is registering, you can check if the email conforms to RFC 822 grammar by using:

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //Valid email!
}
```

Comment: i don' want to send anything :/ when i search i find some thing called Mx record how to use it

Comment: @user2993931 You can't see if the email address exists. The domain could be correct but the email mightn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You can if the the domain of the email address entered has a valid MX record using the below code:

```
checkdnsrr(preg_replace('/^[^@]+@/', '', $emailAddress), 'MX');
```

But checkdnsrr() doesn't work on Windows platforms